# Javascript heap out of memory in Azure Functions hosted via custom docker image

Tags: javascript, docker, memory-management, azure-functions, heap-memory

How can we increase the JS memory limit in the hosted Azure environment? The current limit is set to 2 GB for a node 16 linux environment.

**Additional details :**
Function Plan : EP3 (14GB)
OS : Linux

`context.log('Heap Statistics = ', v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit / (1024 * 1024));` - returns 4144 MB in local and 2096 MB in hosted Azure environment.

Since we are using a custom docker image, I also tried increasing the memory through my docker file but that didn't work.

Docker File :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node16

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \

AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

#Setting Heap Memory to 8GB
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \

npm install

#RUN Custom dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

We are able to increase the memory limit using this app setting on Linux. It's working as expected now.

languageWorkers__node__arguments=--max-old-space-size=8192

[image]